# weird error when passing pthread_t to function

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a C header file which defines the following function:

```
void my_func(pthread_t tid);
```

This is defined by another function:

```
void my_func(pthread_t tid) {
...
```

When I compile, it says:

```
****.h:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘pthread_t’
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You need to `#include <pthread.h>` in the header file so that `pthread_t` is in scope for the `my_func()` prototype.

Without the `#include` the compiler does not recognize `pthread_t` as a type, but it needs a type before the argument.

The error `expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘pthread_t’` is saying just that. You need a type (specifier-qualifier-list) before a parameter (‘pthread_t’).